# Laravel ignores large post request data from Ajax request

Tags: laravel, post, request, limit, missing-data

The Laravel `$request` variable ignores big data, but if I use...

```
$rawPostData = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

I can get all data from the request, even if I have to increase `post_max_size` from the php.ini file, but I still face this issue.

Comment: hm good question, can you verify both the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` ini properties? The `post_max_size` should always be greater than the other. I'm not sure if the properties apply to `file_get_contents()` (it could be a stream). Maybe the only limit this function has is the current PHP memory limit?

Comment: I have increased  `post_max_size`  and `upload_max_filesize ` but still there is some limitation that I am not able to get last request data ,  all data is building using js and at end getting that response  but failed